# Can you Build a Single Package Android App?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

With the release of Android Compose, is it possible to produce single package apps, in which every part of the source code of the app is stored in one long file?

I would like to build one to help me understand why Model-View-ViewModel is so important.

I expect it would fail terribly, but at the same time be quite instructive if it's possible.

Comment: Do you mean single package or single file? Single package (module) apps can be built even without compose.

Comment: I mean single file, I thought I had checked online and seen that package meant file in the Android lexicon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically do this even without Compose since you can have different classes in one file.

Writing all your code in one file isn't that directly related to architectural patterns. As I am pretty sure you can even do MVVM in one file. Writing all code in one file is just bad practice and anyone who has written a single (even small) program knows why it's just a headache.

The computers don't care if your code is in 100 files or one. It just makes it harder to jump into the parts of code you want. Also, it slows down your editor. Assuming you don't write your code properly but just in one file, the program performance should not be affected.

You don't always need to use MVVM or any other architectural pattern to write a clean codebase. You need to pick your architectural pattern based on your needs. Just following architectural patterns in your code does not automatically make your code readable or good.

Comment: Thankyou! I am fuzzily aware of the fact using MVVM is a really good choice for app building. Generally though, I need to learn my own lessons to realise why something matters. The feel of Android programming seems extremely dogmatic to me, coming from python.